# Compiling a Flex Library with a source attachment using compc or FlashBuilder

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flexbuilder, swc, compc

I am trying to compile a Library SWC using FlashBuilder while retaining the references to the source code so that asdocs will still appear and the debugger will show source code when there is a problem. The results I want are similar to what you get when you set a "source-attachment" in the "ActionScript Build Path" settings panel. ([see pic](http://tweetphoto.com/yglobv6c))

Is this possible? Is there a flag that I can set in FlashBuilder or `compc` to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't build source into SWC files. However, you compile your SWC with a `-debug` flag it will retain markers to source file transitions. If you have a debug version of your SWC and the source in a folder then you can edit the "Source Attachment" for your library and point it at the source folder. Then you'll be able to step through the source in the debugger.